# How to use typescript with for loop

Tags: typescript

I made a code like below.
And it's says

> object is possibly undefined.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much for reading it.

```
  for (let i; i < bags.length; i += 1) {
    manager.addDocument(bags[i].language, bags[i].saying, bags[i].intent);
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the surrounding code and the types of these variables. Also, did you mean to do `let i = 0;` instead of `let i;`?

Comment: @Nicholas Tower Oh, you 're right. I forgot to put i=0... Thank you so much